# Too much Data using DISTINCT MAX

Tags: sql, max, sql-server-2014, distinct, multiple-select

I want to see the last activity each individual handset and the user that used that handset. I have a table `UserSessions` that stores the last activity of a particular user as well as what handset they used in that activity. There are roughly 40 handsets, yet I always get back way too many records, like 10,000 rows when I only want the last activity of each handset. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(UserSessions.LastActivity), Handsets.Name,Users.Username
FROM UserSessions
INNER JOIN Handsets on Handsets.HandsetId = UserSessions.HandsetId
INNER JOIN Users on Users.UserId = UserSessions.UserId 
WHERE 
Handsets.Name in (1000,1001.1002,1003,1004....)
AND Handsets.Deleted = 0
GROUP BY UserSessions.LastActivity, Handsets.Name,Users.Username
```

I expect to get one record per handset of the users last activity with that handset. What I get is multiple records on all handsets and dates over 10000 rows

Comment: This is because one hand set may used by multiple users and as you are grouping by USERs, you are getting Hand Set wise and user wise last action details.

Answer (score 0):

You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

This `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates, so `SELECT DISTINCT` isn't needed.

```
SELECT MAX(UserSessions.LastActivity), Handsets.Name, Users.Username
FROM UserSessions
INNER JOIN Handsets on Handsets.HandsetId = UserSessions.HandsetId
INNER JOIN Users on Users.UserId = UserSessions.UserId 
WHERE Handsets.Name in (1000,1001.1002,1003,1004....)
  AND Handsets.Deleted = 0
GROUP BY Handsets.Name, Users.Username
```

Comment: Thanks Jarlh!, k that brought back only around 1000 rows. I think this is because different users use the same handset? I only want the last activity( only one record) for each handset. Any other ideas to stream line the query?

Comment: Do you want the username too for that last activity (per handset)? (If it's not needed, just remove Users.Username from SELECT list and from GROUP BY clause.)

Comment: Yes I need the username to find out who had it last.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `DISTINCT MAX`.  You have `SELECT DISTINCT` which ensures that all columns referenced in the `SELECT` are not duplicated (as a group) across multiple rows.  And there is `MAX()` an aggregation function.

As a note:  `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.

You seem to want:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT h.Name, u.Username, MAX(us.LastActivity) as last_activity,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY h.Name ORDER BY MAX(us.LastActivity) desc) as seqnum
      FROM UserSessions us JOIN
           Handsets h
           ON h.HandsetId = us.HandsetId INNER JOIN
           Users u
           ON u.UserId = us.UserId 
      WHERE h.Name in (1000,1001.1002,1003,1004....) AND
            h.Deleted = 0
      GROUP BY h.Name, u.Username 
     ) h
WHERE seqnum = 1
```